# How to check SOAP webservice connectivity

Tags: android, soap

I'm developing an android application using SOAP webservice. In this app, I need check the connectivity of the webservice, because if the connection is available i have to show the data in online mode and  if the connection is not available i have to show the data in offline mode ie. I'm using SQLlite database to store the data from the webservice

How can my application test for availability of the server, to control whether the application runs in online or offline mode?

Comment: I think it's hilarious that you felt it necessary to remove a horizontal line but you left all the grammatical errors, incorrect casing of personal pronouns, number disagreement and missing words unchanged.

Comment: are you looking for code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this , I followed this method

1. I create a **Pogo Function (web-method)** in my web-service (server) to to check
   connectivity
2. Create a method to in client side to call the web-method . While i Enter into the app for first time ,I call this client method
   from the phone using client function .Then wait for the response.The client method should be surrounded by **try-catch** block
3. If any exception or timed out happened the response will be null and go to exception stage.So
   buy checking the response . I set a **flag (boolean or integer variable)** on base of the state of
   response **(null or not null)** to decide off-line or on-line
   mode

**Example with code**

```
    public class CallSOAP {

private String SOAP_ACTION="your action url";
private String OPERATION_NAME="";//The web method OR web service you are going to call
private final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE=SOAP_ACTION;
private  final String SOAP_ADDRESS=Configuration.WEB_SERVICE_URL;//ip-address of serever where you host your service 
private Exception exception;
private String ErrorMsg="";
private String TERST_URL="" ;
public Object call(String MethodeName,ArrayList<PropertyInfo> Parameters){
  this.OPERATION_NAME=MethodeName;
  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);
 if(Parameters != null && Parameters.size()>0){
   for(PropertyInfo propertyInfo : Parameters){
      request.addProperty(propertyInfo);
 }
}

SoapSerializationEnvelope  envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet= true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE httpTransport =null;
if(!this.TERST_URL.equals(""))
  httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(this.TERST_URL);
else
  httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
 Object Response =null;
 try{
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+OPERATION_NAME, envelope);
    Response=envelope.getResponse();
  }
 catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
     this.ErrorMsg="Unable to connect";
      Response=null;
     this.exception=ex;
  }
  catch (IOException ie) {
   this.ErrorMsg="Unable to connect";
  Response=null;
   this.exception=ie;
  }
   catch (Exception e) {
    this.ErrorMsg="Unable to connect";
    Response=null;
    this.exception=e;
 }
      return Response;
   }
}
```

In the code `ErrorMsg="Unable to connect";` shows the connection is not available now .So i set the response to null and you can pass this response to activity and check it over there

Refer [this](http://javatutorialspoint.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-web-service-access-using-ksoap2.html)

Comment: Now I have another doubt that is  how to do the data synchronization from online to offline or vice versa.Suppose my app is in offline mode,If I updated something on my local Database(Sqlite) then when network connectivity comes the updated things have to reflect on the Soap Webservice.What can I do for this situation?

Comment: it's better to post another question regarding your new doubt . if this question helps you to solve your issue please up vote my answer so others can have it useful

Comment: check i had edited the code , so you can understand it clear. Please post your new doubt with details in as new question

Answer (score 0):

At design time you can point a web browser at the webservice and examine the response. It you don't get a response, or not what you expect, you can get more detail using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/home)

At run-time you can simply attempt to access the server in a try/catch exception handler. Define a public bool IsOnline on something that's visible with appropriate scope, and set it true after successful execution and set it false in the exception handler. It's been decades since I used Java but this is the same approach you would use in practically any OO semiprocedural language, like C# or C++ or Java or for that matter VB.

Comment: I dont need tool while running my app itself I have to check for connectivity with server.

Comment: Sorry I was so slow responding. The answer you accepted contains an example very similar to what I suggested, except that I don't bother to create a pogo function to call, I fold this into the exception handler that you should always have around these calls.